# Use differential form to indicate orientation of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

> A manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ is orientable if and only if it has a global nowhere vanishing $n$-form.

[Here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/botttu.pdf) is a proof from *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* by Bott and Tu (p. 29, proposition 3.2). They used the pull-back of a coordinate map for the differential form. But how can the original manifold have a differential form without local coordinates? Can anyone explain this proof or provide me a clearer proof from other books?

Comment: Unless you have a special manifold $M$, like a hypersurface in $\Bbb R^n$, how do you expect to write down a differential form on $M$ in a global fashion?

Comment: @TedShifrin That's what I'm confused about. But the book I refer to actually used the word "global".

Comment: They're just emphasizing that the differential form is everywhere defined (and smooth). "Global" does not signify that they can write down a single formula like $\omega = z\,dx\wedge dy + y\,dz\wedge dx + z\,dx\wedge dy$.